# Accessing data members of an object from a list

Tags: c++

So BCD is a list of objects of another class BankCustomerDetails. BCD is also a     data member of a class BankSystem.
Let's say I want to access the second customer's name from the list, something like this:-
BCD[1].Name
But this is not working.

```
  class BankSystem
  {
    private:
        std::list<BankCustomerDetails>BCD;

    public:
        std::list<BankCustomerDetails>  GetBankCustomerDetails();
        void SetBankCustomerDetails(std::list<BankCustomerDetails>&);
        int GetTotalCustomerCount();
        void Create_AddCustomerAccount_BankSystem(BankCustomerDetails&);

        bool SearchCustomerDetails_byName(std::string);  
        bool SearchCustomerDetails_byAccountNumber(unsigned long int);

        void UpdateCustomerDetails_byAccountNumber(std::string ,unsigned long int );

        void DepositMoney_byAccountNumber(unsigned long int ,double);

        void WithdrawMoney_byAccountNumber(unsigned long int , double);

        double BalanceInquiryofCustomer_byAccountNumber(unsigned long int );

        void DeleteCustomerDetails_byAccountNumber(unsigned long int );

        void DisplayAllCustomerDetails();

   };



  class BankCustomerDetails
  {
    private:
        std::string Name;
        unsigned long int Account_Number;
        double Account_Balance;
    public:

        BankCustomerDetails();
        BankCustomerDetails(std::string, unsigned long in, double);

        std::string GetBankCustomerName(); 
        unsigned long int GetBankCustomerAccount_Number();
        double GetBankCustomerAccount_Balance();

        void SetBankCustomerName(std::string&); 
        void SetBankCustomerAccount_Number(unsigned long int&);
        void SetBankCustomerAccount_Balance(double&);

        void AcceptBankCustomerDetails();
        void DisplayBankCustomerDetails();
   };
```

And This is What i want to do:-
At Client.cpp

```
string nm;
BankSystem BS;
cout<<"Enter The Customer Name to Search Details"<<endl;
cin>>nm;
int flag = BS.SearchCustomerDetails_byName(nm);
```

At BankSystem.cpp

```
bool BankSystem::SearchCustomerDetails_byName(std::string name)
{
    //Need to Implement
     for(int i = 0; i < BCD.size(); i++){
        if(BCDName = name)
           return true;
     }
return false;
}
```

Comment: I can' t edit the header files. I am just allowed to implement the functions.
I  want to implement this with iterator.

Comment: Well thank you for pointing, but why the problems not deserve the c++faq and c++11 tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `std::list` elements with an index and square brackets. I recommend using a `std::vector` instead of a `std::list`. Then you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < BCD.size(); i++) {
    if (BCD[i].GetBankCustomerName() == name) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Of course you could also do the same thing with a `list` but then you have to rewrite the loop using an iterator.

```
std::list<BankCustomerDetails>::iterator iterator;
for (iterator = intList.begin(); iterator != intList.end(); ++iterator)
    if (iterator->GetBankCustomerName() == name) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Still I recommend using the `vector` because it almost always has better performance.

Two more notes:

- List `itemBCD[i].Name` does not work because `Name`is private.
- The comparison operator is `==` and not `=`.

Comment: Thank  you Frank for replying. But i cannot change the header files. It would be good i can access the elements with iterator. Can you explain it please?

Comment: I am getting this error
cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const BankCustomerDetails' to 'BankCustomerDetails &'
And exactly iterator->GetBankCustomerName() means

Comment: @Mukul: Then remove the `const_` from the iterator declaration. Actually getter functions like `GetBankCustomerName` should be `const` because they don't modify the object, but in your case, it isn't. Since you cannot edit the header, you have to use an non-const iterator. An iterator i a pointer to the current list element. With the `->`operator you dereference it and apply a function on the current element.

Comment: You are a saviour. Thank You. Is there some way i can add here at stackoverflow. I may be asking a lot, but i would like to be connected to you on some sns linkedin or fb.

Comment: @Mukul: At stackoverflow you say thank you by upvoting answers (and questions) and by marking an answer as accepted (which you already did). Both will increase the author's reputation.